# Read list back in angular without using ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of divs that I want to be able to drag and move in the list. I got this part but what I need is to then read the list back and be able to tell the div order based on an id or some kind of disingusing name on each div. Cant set these divs up in the background and use a ngrepeat to populate this list. I have tried just putting the ul in the model `<ul ui:sortable ng:model="list">`, a model on each div `<div class="item" ng:model="list.one">one</div>` and an id on the div `<div class="item" id="one">one</div>` and it always comes back as undefined. Have my work in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q3m4Loq5/

Comment: This library helped a lot when I did something similar http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

Comment: I had read that before, its what gave me the idea of trying ngmodel on the individual div. No idea what else I could use on the page.